# Polylang language slugs on URL corrupt scripts src

Tags: wordpress, scripting, src, polylang

I am using Polylang free to create a multilingual Wordpress website. My scripts are being loaded like this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/themename/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which is **true for the default language** because Polylang does not change the default url: sitename/post.

**When switching to English the url changes**, therefore script files are lost, because there is no corresponding locale structure: sitename/**en**/post.

Console error in inspector (ignore link):

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:8888/sitename/en/wp-content/themes/themename/js/scripts.js”.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
It's not Polylang's fault or anything.
Script src should go like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```